# Mockito: Mocked instance is not injected after annotating spring bean with @RefreshScope

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

My test setup is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class ExampleServiceTest {

   @Resource(name = "exampleService")
   @InjectMocks
   private ExampleService ExampleService;

   @Mock
   private ServiceB serviceB;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }
}
```

ExampleService has been annotated with @RefreshScope, since that annotation was added the real implementation of ServiceB is injected in ExampleService when the test runs.

Comment: @racraman Correct. This is a duplicate and can be closed. Thanks